# Axis 243SA transmit.cgi

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an 2-way audio apps on Android using Axis 243-SA IPCam. I tried to open an output stream (using Java) to feed the audio data in (via "transmit.cgi") but just all rejected (both on Windows desktop or android). I am not sure if the device works with the feature or not. Is there anybody that once make the feature work? What is the setting required (I enabled the full-duplex mode). Or is there any prerequisites (e.g. login/connection established) for the feature? Thanks......

Best regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

i have an axis cam and i use the vapix library to send audio in c#. if you want send me your code. I will test on my cam. Regards